# Not able to upload build on iTunes because of instabug

Tags: module, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, instabug

I am using Appcelerator instabug module 1.1.1 for my project. But when I am going to upload this build to iTunes (For test) it throwing this error.

I googled lot but didn't get solution.

Also I tried by removing instabug file from instabug.framework/instabug and instabug.framework/version/A/instabug but by doing this I am not able to run project.

[image: Here what I get (Error for instabug)]
Please help me.

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: Did you solve your issue ?

Comment: Did you ask the [maintainer of the module](http://gitt.io/search?q=instabug) you are using?

Answer (score 0):

This means that instabug.a is somehow included in your final .ipa file (you can change the extension to .zip, unzip and show contents of your app folder via "show package contents". If you can find instabug.a there, then you have to figure out how and fix it. This should fix your issue.